# How to write a Doxygen comment for variadic function, i.e., a function with undefined number of arguments?

Tags: php, function, comments, doxygen, variadic

I am trying to write a doxygen block comment for a function with unlimited number of parameters, then I couldn't find a right tag for it. Supplied parameters should all be strings, and they will be concatenated in the function to form a new string.

What is the right use of doxygen tags?

Comment: Just /write/ it. Documentation is just that, it's not supposed to be executable or formal, imho

Comment: There's a new feature in PHP 5.6, which will make this way easier. http://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2013/08/potential-variadic-function-syntax-for-php-56

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A pattern I see frequently in [phpdoc](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html) (the format of which doxygen understands) is:

```
/** 
 * Shortdesc.
 * Longdesc.  Longdesc.  Longdesc.  Longdesc.  
 * @param mixed $something Description
 * @param mixed ... Description
 */
    function foo() { ... }
```

Yes, literally `...` as the variable name.

Comment: The `...` is incorrect syntax! The correct syntax is `$paramname,...`

Comment: @Fred, at the time I wrote this **three years ago**, it was correct.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the syntax on the phpDocumentor is `$paramname,...`

```
/**
 * Builds a file path with the appropriate directory separator.
 * @param string $segments,... unlimited number of path segments
 * @return string Path
 */
function file_build_path(...$segments) {
    return join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $segments);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to have an authoritative link to support your answer!

Comment: You're right @Benjamin http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html